# Synchronize at the end of multiple Fluxes, like subscribe() with then()

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have different `Flux`es that do something, e.g. store values in a database or simply print them out. All are finite and I would like to perform an action after all `Flux`es are completely consumed:

```
public void run(String... args) {

    Flux<String> firstFlux = Flux.just("a", "b", "c");
    Flux<Integer> secondFlux = Flux.just(1, 2, 3);
    Flux<Object> thirdFlux = Flux.just(1, "2", 3);

    firstFlux
            .doOnComplete(() -> log.info("first Flux has completed."))
            .subscribe(s -> insertIntoDbString(s));

    secondFlux
            .doOnComplete(() -> log.info("second Flux has completed."))
            .subscribe(i -> insertIntoDbInteger(i));

    thirdFlux
            .doOnComplete(() -> log.info("third Flux has completed."))
            .subscribe(o -> insertIntoDbObject(o));

    // do something after all Fluxes have completed:
    // log.info("all Fluxes have completed.");

}

private void insertIntoDbObject(Object s) {
    log.info("inserting Object: {}", s);
}

private void insertIntoDbInteger(Integer s) {
    log.info("inserting Integer: {}", s);
}

private void insertIntoDbString(String s) {
    log.info("inserting String: {}", s);
}
```

How can I achieve this? I thought, I could use `then()` for each `Flux` to receive `Mono<Void>`s, collect those and use the `doOnComplete()` there but then I don't seem to be able to subscribe to the `Flux` anymore.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You don't care about passing foward values emitted by each flux, just about completing each of them, the most approriate operator is `Mono.when`. It clearly signalizes, that You won't need emitted data, just the information, that fluxes completed.

```
Mono.when(
    firstFlux
            .doOnComplete(() -> log.info("first Flux has completed."))
            .doOnNext(s -> insertIntoDbString(s)),

    secondFlux
            .doOnComplete(() -> log.info("second Flux has completed."))
            .doOnNext(i -> insertIntoDbInteger(i)),

    thirdFlux
            .doOnComplete(() -> log.info("third Flux has completed."))
            .doOnNext(o -> insertIntoDbObject(o))
).doOnSuccess(aVoid -> log.info("all Fluxes have completed."));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Flux.merge` to merge all flux and replace your subscribe method by `doOnNext` like :

```java
    Flux.merge(
           firstFlux
                .doOnComplete(() -> log.info("first Flux has completed."))
                .doOnNext(s -> insertIntoDbString(s)),
           secondFlux
                .doOnComplete(() -> log.info("second Flux has completed."))
                .doOnNext(s -> insertIntoDbInteger(s)),
           thirdFlux
                .doOnComplete(() -> log.info("third Flux has completed."))
                .doOnNext(s -> insertIntoDbObject(s))
    )
    .doOnComplete(() -> log.info("All flux has completed."))
```